# Checking if the voices in two audio files are the same

Tags: audio, voice-recognition

For academic purposes, I was asked to develop a software that can easily help check whether the voice in a first audio is the same as the voice in a second audio.

But before I spend some precious days of my life on this project, I first wanna know if such a software or Python library already exists, preferably open source.

I'd provide two files audio1.wav and audio2.wav representing two speakers in continuous speech. The software or Python library will then answer me YES, or NO. The language could be any main stream language.

Is there such a library/software?

Comment: I don't think you want to have "speech recognition" as I think this is more like speech to text but more check whether or not the frequency etc. of the speaker is the same to identify the speaker. However I don't know the term for this.

Comment: You might try a neural network solution. Tensorflow?

Comment: @unor I think OP wants to know if the 2 files are from the same speaker / reader.

Comment: @albert: Yes, that’s how I understood it, too. Is the title misleading? If so, feel free to suggest an [edit] :)

Comment: @unor Rereading the title looks OK, don't know why at first thought it is misleading maybe I would have formulated it like "Check if 2 audio files are by the same speaker" but this is essential the same as what you wrote.